# How should I make a text box continous instead of making a new line after it completes a line in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter, and I want to put a textbox which only continues to take text without creating a new line after it reaches the screen size limit, like I want it to be scrollable in Horizontal direction if it reaches the screen size limit, so how to do that? Here is the code for only the textbox part

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Container(
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 12, 25),
      child: Text(
        _input,
        style: GoogleFonts.titilliumWeb(
          fontSize: 50.0,
          color: Colors.grey[800],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    alignment: Alignment(1.0, 1.0),
  ),
)
```

Comment: My guess is something like `SingleChildScrollView(child: TextField(...), scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,... )`

Comment: Oh, I understood "continues to take text without creating a new line after it reaches the screen size limit" to mean it's a TextField for user input... if not, just change that to a Text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for both a `Text` and a `TextField`:

[image]

### Scrollable `Text`

In order to achieve this, place your scrollable content (here, your container) inside a `SingleChildScrollView`.

```
SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.amber.shade300,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Text(
      'Fear is the path to the dark side. Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.',
      style: GoogleFonts.titilliumWeb(
        fontSize: 24.0,
        color: Colors.grey[800],
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

### Scrollable `TextField`

Here, I used `IntrinsicWidth` to make the text centered with its prefixed icon and then scrollable.

```
Container(
  height: 48.0,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 0.0),
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.amber.shade300,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Colors.brown,
      width: 3.0,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
  ),
  child: Center(
    child: IntrinsicWidth(
      child: TextField(
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
          hintText: 'Search',
          border: InputBorder.none,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

---

### Full source code for easy copy-paste

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.amber.shade300,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text(
              'Fear is the path to the dark side. Fear leads to anger. Anger leads to hate. Hate leads to suffering.',
              style: GoogleFonts.titilliumWeb(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                color: Colors.grey[800],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the user wants his `TextField` to be horizontally scrollable.

Comment: Oh, really? Ok, I will update the answer for both, then.